# how can I fix the button position without use floating

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems to align correctly the buttons on side by side. I need to build a solution without use the float resource. See it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Documento sem título</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
            }
            a {
                display:inline-block;
                padding: .63em;
                border:1px solid #ccc;
                position:relative;
            }
            .b2 {
                padding: .0em 1em .0em 2.1em;
                text-decoration:none
            }
            .icon {
                position:absolute;
                width:16px;
                height:16px;
                background-color:#999;
                top:50%;
                margin-top:-8px;
                left:2px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style="background-color:#f0f0f0; margin-top:50px; position:relative; height:22px; padding:4px;"> <a href="#"><span class="icon"></span></a>

            <div style="display:inline-block; width:2px; height:22px; background-color:#666;"></div> <a href="#"><span class="icon"></span></a>
 <a href="#" class="b2"><span class="icon"></span><span>Casa d wqe dde qeasd sd</span></a>

        </div>

<h2 style="background:#999"> test</h2>

<a href="#" class="b2"><span class="icon"></span><span>Casa d wqe dde qeasd sd</span></a>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Im not sure what button your talking about and what you expect to be happening.

Comment: Clean up css: Put every inline style to a css class. So it is hard to repair.

Comment: the 3rd button (icon and text) - see: http://s11.postimage.org/b8iytw143/Untitled_5.png

Comment: you want align your links? in this case,inline? your button is your group of: <a> where you place the link that you want go to, and the <span> is where you put your icon, to make one button?

Comment: yes. I need to copy this solution: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/commandButton.jsf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this here:

```
div .b2 {
    top:-6px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u59xD/)

Comment: This is not a good solution I think, 'cause I'll need to do this on all places that I use the button.

Comment: Your example is messy too. So far I see no problem with this hack.

Comment: I need to copy this solution: primefaces.org/showcase/ui/commandButton.jsf

Comment: The problem in this code still remains. As you can see, the span-text alignment is incorrect.

Comment: It's cool, but I need to have a 1px border on my button and a 2px padding. Add .b2{ border:1px solid #ccc; padding:2px} andd you will see the bug.

Comment: Instead .b2, use "a" (a {...}) simply.

Comment: If you run my initial code, you will see exactly what I need and the alignment problem.

Comment: lololol You are the Genius of the Lamp. Good solution! Very cool! Really thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about using an unordered list item? See this jsFiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QtndN/)

You set it to be inline using the CSS properties like this:

```
li {
list-style:none;
display:inline;
}
```

Comment: The ul/li is out of this context, because this is only a button.

Comment: What do you mean? You're still treating as a button... you're just using the ul/li as a way to align

Comment: hmm.. it's strange, I think, a ul/li to make a single button. In some cases I will need mix the text with buttons...